# How can I find and copy using gsutil?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I know how to do it with for but is there an easy way?

```
touch temp/foo
for i in $(find my-dir/* -newer temp/foo);
do
gsutil -m cp -r "$i" gs://my-bucket/
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`gsutil cp -I`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) parameter should help with this. It allows you to read the list of files to copy from stdin.

I think this would work:

```
find my-dir/* -newer temp/foo | gsutil -m cp -I gs://my-bucket/
```